# Identical results over averaging of values

Tags: java, function, return, average

I am trying make a function to get an average of total scores of all students in the school for a certain year but somehow the output keeps giving me 0.0 I know if I take out the else statement the function will work but if the year entered does not exist then the outcome will be NaN but the outcome I want is 0.0 if the year does not exist.

```
public double getClassAverage(int schoolYear){
    int count = DEFAULT_ZERO;
    double totalScore = DEFAULT_DOUBLE_ZERO;
    for (School student : studentCensus){
        int year = student.getSchoolYear();
        double score = student.getScore();
        if ( schoolYear == year){
            count++;
            totalScore = totalScore + score;
        }else{
            return totalScore;
        }
    }
    return totalScore / count;
}
```

Can someone please give me a hand?  Thank you~

Comment: thanks everyone, omg I missed the obvious again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return 0 if no student is in the given year. This avoids division by zero. And as you mention there's no need for your else case within the loop:

```
public double getClassAverage(int schoolYear){
    int count = DEFAULT_ZERO;
    double totalScore = DEFAULT_DOUBLE_ZERO;
    for (School student : studentCensus){
        int year = student.getSchoolYear();
        if ( schoolYear == year){
            count++;
            double score = student.getScore();
            totalScore = totalScore + score;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        return totalScore / count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I see no need for the constants `DEFAULT_ZERO` and `DEFAULT_DOUBLE_ZERO`, just replace them with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Take the return out of the if so all entries are processed.

When you have exited from the loop, return 0.0 if count is zero, otherwise return your current expression.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to return the current value if the schoolYear is not the year of student x? Don't you simply want to SKIP that student then, which means removing the else-block? And yes, you will have to check count to be greater than zero before dividing by it...

```
// We may not divide by Zero, otherwise NaN, so return 0.0 then...
if (count == DEFAULT_ZERO) 
   return 0.0;

// Otherwise return the actual result...
return totalScore / count;
```